# Problem when linking onclick button with a simple JS function

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I've been trying to apply some HTML/CSS functionality to the simple JS code you see below, which consists of returning a random sentence based on two arrays.

I would like to create a simple onclick button showing the sentences generated but I still can't get it to work. Do you have any ideas or clues? I've managed to get it done with variables/text but I have some issues when it comes to accessing the function, which is of course the point of the program.

Thank you all in advance for the help.

JS:

```
const personArr = ["Father Burgundy", "Constable Grey"];
const locationArr = ["the sauna", "the larder"];

const selectArr = (array) => {
 return(array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)]);
}

const createMessage = () => {
 const message = "It was " + selectArr(personArr) + " in " + selectArr(locationArr)"!";
 return message;
};

const init = () => {
 const message = createMessage();
 console.log(message);
};

init();

----------------------------

function demo() {
 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = init();
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id="btn" onclick="demo()">Click here!</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Your `init()` function should return the actual content for the "output" element. Now it returns nothing. Have you tried to `return message;` as you did in the `createMessage()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to return value from the `init()` function, so here is a working jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/vuks89/2cy1fbkd/

```js
const init = () => {
 const message = createMessage();
 console.log(message);
 return message;
};
```

Also, I'm not sure why you need a call to `init();` after its definition.
If it's just for this use case, it's likely unnecessary, because it will be called once button has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Return the message in init() and add + before the last string i createMessage()

```js
const personArr = ["Father Burgundy", "Constable Grey"];
const locationArr = ["the sauna", "the larder"];

const selectArr = (array) => {
 return(array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)]);
}

const createMessage = () => {
 const message = "It was " + selectArr(personArr) + " in " + selectArr(locationArr) + "!";
 return message;
};

const init = () => {
 const message = createMessage();
 console.log(message);
  return message;
};

function demo() {
 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = init();
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="demo()">Click here!</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```